# Picking the right test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I have been learning C# for one and a half year and I also learn Java from time to time. I don't have much experience yet and especially when it comes to testing my code and until now I have always tested manually by interacting with the GUI or writing small test programs. Recently while learning Java I came across JUnit testing and I wondererd if the same exists for Visual C#. In Visual Studio 2017 I have the option of creating a **MSTest Test Project**, **NUnit Test Project**, **xUnit Test Project** or **Unit Test Project**.

I have found examples of people using these different projects but I couldn't figure out **what's the big difference or which one should be used when**.

Comment: Personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has it's own test framework, aptly named 'MSTest', which is a simple and easy way to get started. OFten, you'll see complaints from people who find it slow, however, a few tweaks to the settings here & there, and you'll find it performs briliantly.

However, there are more popular test frameworks such as nUnit, xUnit. All have good documentation on how to get started, and these days, there aren't too many differences between them. xUnit has some neat features that you may find interesting, however, it's first in advanced scenarios that these frameworks differ, and you'll have to have pretty specific needs before you find a limitation.

I would suggest you to start on MSTest, nUnit or xUnit, try them out, make one DLL for each of them in your project and see which one you like more.

Comment: So as long as my tests are not too advanced or complicated any of these should be fine? If the differences aren't anything too big I guess I will just try out the popular ones (nUnit and xUnit), since it will be easier to ask or find information if I ever encounter a problem.

Comment: Yup, they're all broadly used and work just fine. Have fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

The different frameworks are not that very different. I would recomend xUnit or NUnit, I prefer xUnit, but it is more of an syntax issue. I think most of them support parameterized input now. The most important is that you create unit tests!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I think I will try both and check out which one I prefer.